# Como alterar limite máximo de conexões simultâneas ao db

Tags: postgresql

Quando eu excedo 100 conexões, recebo o erro:

```
"FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"
```

Como alterar o parâmetro do *postgresql.conf* `max_connections` no Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: Como você está alcançando esse limite?

Comment: São vários aplicativos consumindo este banco de dados. Em momentos de pico atinge-se o limite de 100 conexões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No [Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps), está escrito:

*"Não há limitações de consultas por segundo (QPS) para as instâncias do Google Cloud SQL. Entretanto, existem limites de número de conexões, tamanho e para aplicações rodando no Google App Engine."* (Traduzido do inglês)

[image: screenshot dos limites para conexões ao Google Cloud SQL]
Então tudo indica que essa é uma limitação do tipo de instância sendo utilizado - ou seja, você não poderá mudar a não ser que utilize outro tipo de instância.

> Vale ressaltar que 100 conexões simultâneas não é um número baixo - é interessante verificar a real necessidade e procurar otimizar o uso dessas conexões.

Mais para baixo na página, há o seguinte texto:

***Como devo gerenciar as conexões?***
"A melhor maneira de gerenciar conexões vai depender de cada caso mas, no geral, nós recomendamos utilizar pool de conexões. Pool de conexões irá proteger o banco de dados de uma enorme quantidade de conexões sendo criadas rápido demais, que poderia impactar a performance." (Traduzido do inglês)

Então essa já é uma possível otimização para a sua aplicação.

> Perguntas que ainda precisam ser feitas:

- Por que são necessárias 100+ conexões simultâneas?
- O App está fechando corretamente as conexões depois de usá-las?
- Você está usando um pool de conexões?

Comment: * São vários aplicativos/sistemas consumindo o banco, sendo que em momentos de pico esse limite é excedido.
* Acredito que sim, pois quem gerencia as conexões é um ORM(telerik para c#).
* Não uso pool de conexões(é possível implementar pool no Cloud SQL?).

Comment: @luanfvieira isso já é outra pergunta - mas é [isso](http://www.telerik.com/) que você usa? se for, eles falam sobre connection pooling [aqui](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/api/context-api/backend-configuration/feature-ref-api-context-api-backend-config-connectionpool-config).